# Can you make an app auto download for android on contact with an nfc tag?

Tags: java, android, nfc, nativescript

I have an idea for an app and after doing some research I couldn't find anything that would answer my question, what I want is for when a user touches their android phone off a tag, it auto downloads an app for them, kind of like a QR Code, but specifically nfc.
All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No app can be installed without user interaction. This is required because the user is in charge of the device and he has to manually allow an app to be installed, otherwise you have a great recipe for allowing malicious apps to find their way to your device undetected.

Best you can do is direct them to the play store page with your app, but it is up to the user to decide whether to install it or not.